# How do I combine "x" ammount of characters from two words in batch?

Tags: batch-file

My friend wants to take a name from a list he has generated and create a username from that name.

It doesn't really matter how he gets the name from the list, or that he has a list for that sake, because all he wants to know is the basics of how you can use batch to take the 3 first letters of the first name, and the 3 first letters of the last name, and combine those letters to form a username.

I don't really have any examples to show, and I'm not experienced with batch at all, so I will be hoping you guys can give me a good answer :)

Thanks!

Comment: There are plenty of internet websites with tutorials on batch programming. If your extensive research can't solve the problem, then you're welcome to pose the question to SO. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: @IceArdor I have made some effort researching, but I am having trouble explaining my question to google -_-. I've had a bunch of help here in the past and I'm quite aware that SO wants you to do some research before asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample code that does the indicate task.

For string manipulation in batch file, start reading from set command help (`set /?` from command line). There is a lot of information here at stackoverflow on each of the aspects of batch programming. Try, and when problems found, ask.

```
@echo off

    call :getUserName "John" "Smith" userName
    echo %userName%

    call :getUserName "Jo" "Jones" userName
    echo %userName%

    exit /B

:getUserName Name LastName returnVariable
    setlocal
    rem get parameters
    set "name=%~1"
    set "lastName=%~2"
    rem remove spaces and add some padding
    set "name=%name: =%___"
    set "lastName=%lastName: =%___"
    rem clean and return value: 
    rem   3 characters from position 0 from both parameters
    endlocal & set "%~3=%name:~0,3%%lastName:~0,3%"
    goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a testfile with the names to parse in 'names.txt', containing 2 rows (Richie Rich and Diamond Rock), then made this scripts:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%G in ( names.txt ) do (
   set firsname=%%G
   set lastname=%%H
   set first=!firsname:~0,3!
   set last=!lastname:~0,3!
   echo !first!!last!
)
```

Output is RicRic and DiaRoc. Hope this helps.